# clear visual studio code integrated terminal history on workspace load

Tags: python, json

I am creating a program using visual studio code and python/django, however, I need to be able to clear the integrated terminal history every time I load the workspace, but I cannot figure out how to do so.

The reason is because I regularly terminate the django project, and restart it. Primarily because this is a side project,I have to keep other things open that already slow down my computer, so simply leaving this django project running will not work.

I have tried the following in the ***.code-workspace*** file:

```
{
        "folders": [
                {
                    "path": "."
            }
        ],
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.persistentSessionReviveProcess": "onExit",
                "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 1000,
                "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.history": 0,
                    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
                        "workbench.action.terminal.clearPreviousSessionHistory":"cmd",
                        "terminal.integrated.clear":"cmd",
                        "terminal.integratedterminal.history.clear":"cmd",
                        "terminal.clearPreviousSessionHistory":"cmd",
                },
            },
            "workbench.action.terminal.clearPreviousSessionHistory":"cmd",
            "terminal.integrated.clear":"cmd",
            "terminal.integratedterminal.history.clear":"cmd",
            "terminal.clearPreviousSessionHistory":"cmd",    
}
```

I was expecting it to remove history, and nothing happens. the history shows up, and creates a massively filled terminal.